# execute function on page or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have recursive function as the following :

```
scope.$watch('settings.egg', function () {
                    var index = 0;
                    function inOrder() {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $(".egg").eq(index).removeClass("maximize")
                            $(".egg").eq(index + 1).addClass("maximize")
                            index++;
                            inOrder();
                        }, 3000)
                    };
                    $(".egg").eq(index).addClass("maximize")
                    inOrder();
                })
```

My function execute on load page but I don't want that.
I just want to work click on button not on load page.
How can I do ? 
Please..

Comment: No sure it is clear enough - This function watch for a change on 'settings.egg' - the callback will be executed once the 'settings.egg' will be changed (not on startup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not set up a function that's bound to an ng-click of your button then and set your function within that? For example:

```
scope.buttonClick = function() {
  scope.watchFunc = scope.$watch('settings.egg', function () {
                    var index = 0;
                    function inOrder() {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $(".egg").eq(index).removeClass("maximize")
                            $(".egg").eq(index + 1).addClass("maximize")
                            index++;
                            inOrder();
                        }, 3000)
                    };
                    $(".egg").eq(index).addClass("maximize")
                    inOrder();
                })
}
```

You'd store this in a scope variable so that you could easily call it from another function later on to cancel the $watch. And in your markup:

```
<button ng-click="buttonClick()">Click me to set the watch</button>
```

Comment: I must use ng-model. Could it be another solution ? @Xaniff

Comment: @eagle It'd be helpful if you could elaborate how that factors into your question as well as why you're restricted to using that. If you put this directly in the controller, the $watch is going to be set when said controller instantiates and will execute the callback when the specified model changes. 

If you don't want it set then, don't set it until you want it to and my solution provides that trigger.